# Manipulator settings

Tags: pose-mode, 3d-manipulator

My Manipulator is rotated with the object in pose mode. How can i switch it back to the standard x, y, z, manipulator. I cant find the solution anywhere!!
please help

[image: the picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got transformation orientation switched to Gimbal, change it back to Global.You will find this setting on the bottom toolbar in 3D view.